# SMTP email slow to send with nodemailer and amazon SES

Tags: email, smtp, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send emails inside next.js api functions. I have the following code:

```js
import nodemailer, { SentMessageInfo } from "nodemailer";

export default async ({ to, subject, text, html }: Props) => {
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.AWS_SES_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.AWS_SES_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  console.log("Sending email to", to);

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info: SentMessageInfo = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Me" <help@myemail.io>', // sender address
    to,
    subject,
    text,
    html: html,
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

  return info.messageId;
};
```

Sometimes this can take minutes to send but I have no idea why. How would one go about debugging this? Is it possible that my Amazon SES SMTP server is throttling me? I'm not even sending emails that frequently.

Comment: good question, any solution yet? Br

Comment: What do you mean by "take minutes"? Is that the time spent in `transporter.sendMail` or until the email shows up in the inbox? For the former you can ask amazon's support. For the later, this can depend on many things, varying by the servers involved. It may depend on your sending IP address reputation, how spammy your emails look, and so on.